# Why in extension method I don't have access to some other IServiceCollection extensions in .net Core?

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-6.0

In program.cs I can do

```
services.Configure<Blah>(configuration.GetSection("foo"));
```

But when I create an extension method for `IServiceCollection` there is no `Configure` method to use

```
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public static class ServiceExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
    {
        // I am getting an error in this line 'IServiceCollection does not contain a definition for Configure' 
        services.Configure<Blah>(config.GetSection("foo"));

        return services;
    }
}
```

What is the reason?

Comment: You need to add https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/ package in the project where your extension method is. In the WebApi project, this package is added behind the scenes.

Comment: @funatparties Thank you so much. If you add it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Options package in the project where your extension method is. In the WebApi project, this package is added behind the scenes.